# Xamarin Click only works on 1 view in AbsoluteLayout

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I have a problem. I used the following code to create a Floating Action Button Menu: https://github.com/Polarts/CrossFAB

Now, I added it to my code like this:

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <AbsoluteLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        <ScrollView Orientation="Vertical" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1"
                AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All">
            <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
                <Label Text="Undone" TextColor="Black" FontSize="26" FontAttributes="Bold" Margin="10" />
            </StackLayout>
        </ScrollView>

        <c:FloatingMenu Margin="0, 0, 10, 10" BGColor="Gray" OpenIcon="Share.png" CloseIcon="X.png"
                        AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All">
            <c:FloatingButton x:Name="FB" BGColor="Blue" IconSrc="Facebook.png"/>
            <c:FloatingButton x:Name="TW" BGColor="White" IconSrc="Twitter.png"/>
            <c:FloatingButton x:Name="TB" BGColor="Navy" IconSrc="Tumblr.png"/>
        </c:FloatingMenu>
    </AbsoluteLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

I used an `AbsoluteLayout`, because the `FloatingMenu` needs to be in the bottom right corner, but the problem is that right now, I can use the Floating Action Button, but the scroll of the `ScrollView` isn't working. When I put the `FloatingMenu` code above the `ScrollView`, the `FloatingMenu` stops working and I can only scroll.

How can I use both items for clicks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> PositionProportional, indicates that the x and y values will be
> interpreted as proportional, while the size values are interpreted as
> absolute.

A position of (0,0) puts the child in the upper-left corner, while a position of (1,1) puts the child in the lower-right corner, and a position of (0.5,0.5) centers the child within the AbsoluteLayout.

So you could try to change like below:

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <AbsoluteLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        <ScrollView Orientation="Vertical" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1"
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All">
            <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
                <Label Text="Undone" TextColor="Black" FontSize="26" FontAttributes="Bold" Margin="10" />
               
            </StackLayout>
        </ScrollView>

        <c:FloatingMenu  Margin="0, 0, 10, 10" BGColor="Gray" OpenIcon="Share.png" CloseIcon="X.png"
                    AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="1,1" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional">
            <c:FloatingButton x:Name="FB" BGColor="Blue" IconSrc="Facebook.png"/>
            <c:FloatingButton x:Name="TW" BGColor="White" IconSrc="Twitter.png"/>
            <c:FloatingButton x:Name="TB" BGColor="Navy" IconSrc="Tumblr.png"/>
        </c:FloatingMenu>
    </AbsoluteLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

Answer (score 1):

When you set the `AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1"` and `AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"` on a view, you're saying that you want you want the view to start in the top left corner and you want it to take up the full width and height of the view.

Since you set the LayoutBounds on both your views to this, you essentially have two views that take up the entire screen stacked on top of each other. You can test this out by adding a background color to either of the views and see what happens. Because of this, whichever view you put second is getting the touches, because it's the one on top.

If you want your `FloatingMenu` to be in the bottom right hand corner, you need to fix the layout bounds on that view to reflect that.

Something like this might get you started:

```
<c:FloatingMenu
    Margin="0, 0, 10, 10"
    BGColor="Gray" 
    OpenIcon="Share.png" 
    CloseIcon="X.png"
    AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds=".95,.95,50,50" 
    AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional">
```

This says that we want to put the view 95% over and 95% down the screen with a set width and height of 50. We say `PositionProportional` because we want the position, the first 2 numbers to be read as a proportion, not as absolute values.

You may also need to adjust the layout of the Floating Menu view. I suspect you're doing something like `EndAndExpand` for your Vertical and Horiztonal options that may not work like you expect when you fix the absolute layout.

Make sure to also take a look at the documentation on [AbsoluteLayout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/absolutelayout).

Comment: Thank you, but the buttons below the FabMenu still not working, how can I fix that? All the code of the FabMenu is in the GitHub link at the beginning of my question!

Comment: You probably need to update the width and height in the LayoutBounds. I just threw out 50 because they were nice round numbers. You can set whatever numbers you need. Or you can use AutoSize like `AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds=".95,.95,AutoSize,AutoSize" `